# How to remove a very stealthy virus?

Tags: virus, antivirus, virus-removal, anomaly-detection

I have a virus on my laptop preventing me from installing antivirus, or updating windows or even opening task manager.

i tried running a virus scanner from a portable scanners, the virus disappears and the task manager opens normally and i can install the antivirus when the scanner is running. but after that the virus removes the antivirus and removes all my security tools or scanning tools and for some antiviruses it disable all of its functions.

can anyone help in removing this virus?
noting that i already used kaspersky bootable disk, and many other tools and virus and malware removals.

Comment: Sounds like the best option is to just format and reinstall/restore from a backup.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malwar eremoval site.